# jQuery hide() and show() not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to display a hidden **div** (with a class `.details`) whenever a mouse hover at an element `.tags` in a page. This is working but not as expected.
I want the mouse should be able to enter the displayed `.details` and should even be able to click on its contents as we have here in StackOverflow tags
but the moment the mouse leaves `.tags` everything disappears. How can I delay the appearance of `.details` and have it allow mouse to select 
its content whenever a mouse hovers over `.tags`?

**HTML code:**

```
<div class = 'tags'>
  <div class='details'>
    <a href='a.html'> jQuery </a>
    <a href='b.html'> PHP </a>
    <a href='c.html'> MySQL </a>
    <a href='d.html'> Ruby on Rails </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS code:**

```
.details {
    background-color: rgb(235,243,243);
    border-radius: 7px;
    padding: 3px;
    width: 240px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 5px;
    font-weight: 400;
}
```

**jQuery code:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.details').hide();
    $(document).on('mouseover', ".tags", function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.find('.details').slideDown(100);
    });
    $(document).on('mouseleave', ".tags", function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.find('.details').hide();
    });
});
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Create jsfiddle please, in this code `tags` isn't visible for user.

Comment: I have read your question 3 times and I still cannot understand your issue...
"mouse leaves `.details` everything disappears" - well from your code that is the expected result.
"Delay the appearance" - so you don't want to show the details when the user hovers over the `.tags` div?

Comment: I have copied your code. the `.details` is shown on hover and I am able to click the links. If a move away from the details it is hidden... is this not the expected behaviour?

Comment: @SecretSquirrel: Yes but it is not working here. You can hardly get it stay to move your mouse to `.details`. The moment you leave `.tags`, `.details` disappears but with caution you get to enter it.

Comment: make the `.tags` div size bigger...

Comment: Have done that but the truth is that there is another **div** after `.tags`: `<div class = 'line'></div>` which is meant to show a line between the `.tags` and `.details`. So moving from `.tags` always crosses `.line` before getting to `.details`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create [`jsfiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/frontenddeveloping/6uPQm/) for answer. The problem is in `.parents('.tags')`, because `$this` is already `tabs` element. `And $this.parents('.tags')` returns empty jQuery object.

Answer (score 0):

Add this style to your page and see if this helps

```
.tags {
   height: 100px;
   width: 200px;
}
```

the reason is because the `.tags` div is so small. Even though the `.details` div populates the `.tags` div it doesn't force the size of the element to increase.

which is why it is so hard for you to navigate across the `.details` div

Answer (score -2):

You are hiding the tag that you want to control the mouse over event for.

Also, look at this way of setting up the selector, it makes it far more readable:

```
$(".tags").on('mouseover', function () {
    alert("hi");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tVEkF/

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: He's hiding the tag and then attaching a mouse over event to it. That will not work. I've also provided a better way to attach the event so as not to confuse him. 
How does that not answer the question?